# How do you Keep Group Together across columns in Crystal Report?

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, multiple-columns

I have a multi-column Crystal 2008 report that is grouped on a date field, and I want to prevent that group from being split across the column to column boundary.

Googling it, it seems impossible - no one even has some sort of hack for faking it.

Here is an image of the issue - I would like Friday the 26th to all be in the second column.

[image: Screenshot of Issue in Crystal]

Comment: +1 I've never dealt with using multiple columns before, but this is an interesting problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing is impossible!
While initially discouraged with the voted answer, I kept searching and found something about using a subreport for the "details". Then I used a mailing label, although this may not be necessary, but in my use I wanted each group to have identical size, this worked perfect to make sure the groups stayed together in the columns. It is a little clumsy but seems the subreport won't cross columns.

Anyway this is an old topic, but thought I would leave this here just in case someone dusts it off.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this is impossible for now.

Comment: changed answer to be @defrosted 's answer instead.  Haven't tested it, but it sounds reliable enough.

Comment: Been looking to solve this issue and the marked solution worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Right click the group, select 'Change Group...', select the Options tab, check the 'Keep group together' option.

Comment: 'Keep Group Together' only seems to work between pages, not columns. In fact, it doesn't look as though CR makes any distinction between columns on the same page at all. For example, 'Repeat Group Header' also does not work on columns. Unfortunately, I can't find any way to programmatically differentiate between which column a field prints on. What would be nice is a Print State function that would give you the x,y-coordinate of a printed field...

Answer (score 0):

If you can determine beforehand that you want the group to print on the next column, have a blank detail line extra at the bottom of the detail lines and check the print at bottom of page and suppress it with a formula that is controlled by either a crystal variable or a database field. This is the only way I have found to cause a group to stay together. You find the print at bottom of page in the section expert, add the blank line as the last of your detail lines.

Comment: This might come in handy, but I don't think it would work in my scenario. I don't know from data whether I want the group in the next column or not -- only the layout can tell me that.